# Running SSIS package with linked server through a SQL Job

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, linked-server, sql-job

I have a SSIS 2008 package. In one of the Script task I am calling a stored procedure which is  using Openquery using linked server. I deployed this package with protection level as "EncryptWithPassword" and gave a password to the package. Created a SQL job and edited its command line to include the password. If I login to SQL Server Mgmt Studio with Windows Authentication and run the job manually it runs fine. But when I schedule it then I get an error that "The Communication link to Linked server failed".

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that you launch `job` from default `Run as` login.
You should create credential with your login, so package will have access and priveleges to linked database under your login.
You may read [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/) article for better explanation.